# Добавить еще один DNS резолвер в /etc/nsswitch.conf для VPN

Tags: сеть, dns

Итак, я настроил VPN на своем домашнем роутере и подключаюсь в сеть предприятия со своего компьютера. Маршруты: все запросы `10.0.0.0/8` идут по VPN, остальные (`ya.ru`) - интернет. Мне нужно резолвить домен `tasks.corp.ru`.

- `corp.ru` - существует в публичном DNS
- `tasks.corp.ru` - не существует в публичном DNS, записи `*.corp.ru` также нет
- DNS-резолвер для VPN имеет адрес `10.0.0.1`, со своей задачей справляется

Но я **не** хочу использовать резолвер `10.0.0.1` **постоянно**, так как VPN я включаю только на время работы. То есть после выключения на роутере VPN, DNS резолвер перестает быть доступным.

Сейчас резолвинг происходит так - `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4 mdns4_minimal
```

Я хочу сделать так:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4 mdns4_minimal 10.0.0.1
```

Другими словами, я хочу чтобы на `10.0.0.1` попадали запросы в самую последнюю очередь, то есть если `ya.ru` можно разрулить через `/etc/hosts` или DNS моего провайдера, то пусть так и будет. А если `tasks.corp.ru` - то на `10.0.0.1`. Если выключил VPN - `ya.ru` - открывается, `tasks.corp.ru` - разумеется, нет.

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

- Добавил дополнительный DNS в настройки VPN роутера - не сработало!
- поднимать локально свой DNS-сервер типа bind или unbound не хочется

Как сделать мою задумку?

Comment: [Используйте только совместно с уточняющими метками: [openvpn\], [ppp\], [pptp\], [pppoe\], [ipsec\], [tls\], [ssh\], [wireguard\] и т.п.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vpn)